# Using classes other variables that update in real time

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I'm making a top down car game in C# with monogame. (I tagged XNA because monogame also uses XNA. It's EXACTLY the same)

the game now looks like this:
[image: This is what the car game currently looks like]

Although I'm having some problems with the speed of the car.
I have a variable in the Background class that the speed is increasing, however I'm trying to do the same with the car, but with 1 extra speed so it has the illusion of the car moving further. I have included this in the code of the car:

```
Background b = new Background();
```

The speed in the background increases '0.001' every frame, and is put in the Update part of the class.

*background.cs*

```
public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
  //blahblahcode
  speed += 0.001;
  //blahblahcode
}
```

in the oponnent.cs I have this in the code.

```
public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    float Timer1 = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
    timer1_time -= Timer1;
    int speedp = (int)b.speed + 1;
    Console.WriteLine(b.speed);
    if (timer1_time <= 0)
    {
        timer1_time = 4;
        randNum = rand.Next(3);
        carDrivePos = cardefault_y;

        if (randNum == 0)
        {
            lane = p.posLeft;
        }
        else if (randNum == 1)
        {
            lane = p.posMid;
        }
        else if (randNum == 2)
        {
            lane = p.posLeft;
        }
    }
    carDrivePos += (int)b.speed + speedp;
    carPos = new Vector2(lane, carDrivePos);
}
```

It's a bit weird coded but I understand it and it works, a little.
as you can see I have

```
int speedp = (int)b.speed + 1;
```

which I think should grab the speed of it every frame. But it doesn't. It only grabs from what I have specified in 'Background.cs', which is the number 2. So the car keeps going 2 speed + 1. So the speed is actually 3, so if the background keeps moving faster the car just keeps the same speed.

How can I get it so that it updates the speed like in 'Background.cs'?
Thanks in advance. (Sorry if this is hard to understand)

Comment: What `Console.WriteLine(b.speed)` gives you? And what's the type of `b.speed`?

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be surfaced by taking a look at the variable types:

- `Background.speed` is a double (or similar)
- The `Opponent.Update` method declares `speedp` is an int

In the Background class, the Update method is updating Background.speed:

```
// Background sets the initial value
speed = 2d;

// The Background.Update Method updates the value
speed += 0.001;
// speed now equals 2.001;
```

However, in the Opponent class, the Update method is attempting to use Background.speed as an int which causes the result to be rounded:

```
int speedp = (int)b.speed + 1;
// result will be 3 due to rounding
```

In other words:

```
int speedp = (int)2.001 + 1;
// result will be 3 due to rounding
```

Until `Background.speed` is greater than 2.5, the result will always be 3.

To resolve the issue, `speedp` will need to be a double (or similar) so the precision is not lost due to rounding.

Comment: That didn't fix it. It still thinks it's two.. It seems like it can't see what is updating the Update class, just only what the variable set. so 2. So if my background is moving at 5. the car is still moving at 3.

Comment: Is the `Background` class being created multiple times throughout the app? Or is it being created once and only once and being reference as needed, i.e., from within the `Opponent` class? From what you are describing, the `Background` class in the `Opponent` class is not the same reference that is being updated.

Comment: Yes, what? `Background` is being created in the `game1` class as well as other classes such as `Oppenent`? Or yes, `Background` is only created in the `game1` class and **no where** else in the application?